# MDI Form Designer Error in Resource Images

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am just stuck out of this error.In **MDI** i set Background Image for **Menu-strip**..it all running fine, buti got designer error like this,

[image: MDI Designer Error Image]

its **Mdi.designer.cs** Code Sample..

```
this.MenuStrip1.BackgroundImage = global::WAREHOUSE.Properties.Resources.header;
```

Please Suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this

```
 Image imageNormal = Image.FromFile("Resources\\header.jpg");
 this.MenuStrip1.BackgroundImage = imageNormal ;
```

Comment: Where i can use this Code.

Comment: if you want to set the background image of a form or something like this you should write this code on page_load event.

Comment: ya its working like this,                 `this.menuStrip.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\header.jpg");`

Comment: gr8, my code was right, it was the path problem of your resource folder. Accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: But you're not loading it from the resource file, but from the image in application root folder.

Comment: i just told him a way i use to put image using resources and that worked almost. if it gives the right path of resources folder it will work fine without using application.startuppath

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have a folder named "Resources" with a "header.jpg" file in it. Right? You cannot access files in folders with that code.
Do you want it to be an embedded resource? Then you have to embed the image in the resource file, and then you can access it like that.

Comment: am just import image from its properties resource file

Comment: And you are sure you've added the image to the resource file?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the image sitting in the resource file? Have you double-checked the ID to be correct?

Comment: Yes am just Select Background Image of its Properties and Import from "Project resource file" and click the "Import..." button to add image...